# How to ensure single phase AC polarity?

Tags: single-phase, ac-polarity

The device I'm designing needs to have correct power supply polarity but will be connected to mains supply with unpolarized plug. What automatic and IEC standards compliant methods there are to ensure polarity?

To my suprise monitoring relays for single phase polarity don't seem to exist. Of course any relay between one pole on the supply side and ground could do it but I'm pretty sure it doesn't comply to any standards.

Another solution could be to use an isolation transformer and connect one leg on the output side to ground. That would for sure create neutral and line but I'm not sure whether this would be compliant or not.

Comment: There is no such thing as AC polarity. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you are doing and why, there could be a solution. Devices with unpolarized plugs must not be sensitive to polarity. Why does your device need a specific polarity?

Comment: The machine will have a single phase VFD whose ground leakage current is low enough only if line and neutral are correctly connected.

Comment: My gut-feeling is that this sounds like a dodgy design @Kestis <-- you can prove otherwise by linking the data sheet.

Comment: https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/industrialcontrols-drives-automation-sensors/variable-frequency-drives/powerxl-de1-variable-frequency-drives/de1-vss-user-manual-mn040011en.pdf

It's on the bottom of the page 31 (page 35 of the PDF)

Comment: Looks like a product only allowed for fixed installation, not via polarity-swappable plug.

Comment: That only seems to apply to installation according to UL standards.

Comment: Difference between phase and neutral conductors that neutral connected to ground at power source. For protection purposes. If you need polarized connection but using unpolarized plug, the design is completely wrong.

Comment: Polarized plug with Earth? Is it Schuko?

Comment: Yes, Schuko plug.